# copying from one list box to other listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am working with windows form application using c#. I have two list boxes i.e listbox1 and listbox2 and one button i.e btnall. listbox1 is bind using databind and listbox2 is empty. I want to copy all the items from listbox1 which is binded to other listbox2 which is empty. On the click of btnAll_click event.
I am trying this

```
private void btnAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listbox2.Items.AddRange(listbox1.Items);
}
```

but I am getting data.datarowview instead of the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the items in LIstbox1 and add them one at a time like this:

```
 foreach (var item in Listbox1.Items)
 {
     listbox2.Items.Add(item.ToString());
 }
```

Would that do what you want?

Comment: Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.Items' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only. i am getting this error while trying this.listbox2.items=listbox1.items

Comment: after trying this i am getting system.data.datarowview

Comment: @siddharth Ah ok i think you may need item.something rather than item. Hang on let me try it

Comment: You need to add .ToString() i have tested this code and it works.

Comment: nop yr i have also tried this it giving me same thing system.data.datarowview.i am using   this.shift_MasterTableAdapter1.Fill(this.timeDataSet22.Shift_Master); this code for binding.

Comment: what does the listbox contain then? Is it not just strings?

Comment: I guess since you have accepted my answer that you have worked it out now?

Comment: after binding manually in the codebehind and applying this code work thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
listbox2.DataSource = listbox1.Items;
```

Comment: i am getting same thing system.data.datarowview.not the value

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating the list control via the `DataSource` property try setting `DataSource` and `DataMember`. and dont forget :

```
listBox.DisplayMember = "displayMember";
listBox.ValueMember = "valueMember";
```

else try this:

```
var mylistSource = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in Listbox1.Items)
{
    mylistSource.Add(item.ToString());
}

listBox2.DataSource = mylistSource;
```